# update CheckBoxList values form GridView and save into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkboxlist, updating

I have a student form which is storing the information of student.
[Form Looks Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S2V5.png)

Following is the code. PLEASE tell me how to update multiple checkbox through Checkboxlist

```html
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("SUbjects") %>'>
        <%--OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged--%>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Physics">Physics</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Chemistry">Chemistry</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Biology">Biology</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" onCheckedChanged="onChackedChange" Text='<%# Eval("SUbjects") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

```js
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
             
            int studentid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());//Get Each Row unique value from DataKeyNames
            string studentname = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;//get TextBox Value in EditItemTemplet that row is clicked
            string studentage = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox2")).Text;
            string studentdepartment = ((DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("DropDownList1")).Text;
            string studentgender = ((RadioButtonList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("RadioButtonList1")).Text;
            CheckBoxList studentsubjects = ((CheckBoxList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CheckBoxList1"));

  
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WINCTRL-0938L38; Database=dbUni; Integrated Security=true");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("StudentUpdate", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_id ", studentid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name ", studentname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age ", int.Parse(studentage));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@department ", studentdepartment);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender ", studentgender);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subjects ", studentsubjects);
            }
            
           
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;// no row in edit mode
            FillGrid();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Here is the stored procedure of StudentUpdate

```js
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StudentUpdate]
    (
    @student_id int,
    @name varchar(50),
    @age int,
    @gender nvarchar(50),
    @department nvarchar(50),
    @subjects nvarchar(50)
    )
    AS UPDATE tblStudents set
    NAME=@name,
    AGE=@age,
    DEPARTMENT=@department,
    GENDER=@gender,
    SUbjects=@subjects
    where Student_ID=@student_id
```

This is how I am storing subjects in database at the First Place

```js
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String gender;
            if (rdBtnMale.Checked)
                gender = rdBtnMale.Text;
            else
                gender = rdBtnFemale.Text;

            string subject = "";
            if (cboxPhysics.Checked)
            {
                subject = cboxPhysics.Text;
            }
            if (cboxChemistry.Checked)
            {
                if (subject != "")
                { subject = subject + ","; }
                subject = subject + cboxChemistry.Text;
            }
            if (cboxBiology.Checked)
            {
                if (subject != "")
                { subject = subject + ","; }
                subject = subject + cboxBiology.Text;
            }
```

[In This Image I have applied changes but I am having this warning.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tsdH.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop the all ListItems in the CheckBoxList. With what you are doing now you are only getting the first checked item in the list, not all of them.

```
//create a list to store all the subjects
List<string> studentsubjects = new List<string>();

//find the control in the GridView and cast it back to a CheckBoxList
CheckBoxList subjects = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("CheckBoxList1") as CheckBoxList;

//loop all the items and see if they are checked
foreach (ListItem item in subjects.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        //add the checked value to the list
        studentsubjects.Add(item.Text);
    }
}

//display results
Label1.Text = string.Join(",", studentsubjects);
```

Comment: Define 'not working'? What does `string.Join(",", studentsubjects);` give for a result?

Comment: That has nothing to do with my snippet. You are setting a `SelectedValue` somewhere else that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**.Aspx Code:**

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SUbjects") %>'></asp:Label>
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" SelectMethod="Multi" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("SUbjects") %>'>
        <%--OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged--%>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Physics">Physics</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Chemistry">Chemistry</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Biology">Biology</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" onCheckedChanged="onChackedChange" Text='<%# Eval("SUbjects") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**.CS Code:**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || (e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {
            CheckBoxList chklist = ((CheckBoxList)e.Row.FindControl("CheckBoxList1"));
            string subjects = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label1")).Text;

            string[] subjectslist = subjects.Split(',');

            foreach (string item in subjectslist)
            {
                if (item == "Physics")
                    chklist.Items.FindByText("Physics").Selected = true;
                else if (item == "Chemistry")
                    chklist.Items.FindByText("Chemistry").Selected = true;
                else
                    chklist.Items.FindByText("Biology").Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note:** Don't forget to add `OnRowDataBound` event in GrindView `<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >`

Comment: This is not working. Why are You adding for student_id in foreach loop?
I am having problem just updating CheckBoxList

Comment: As you are accessing controls from `EditTemplate` and if you want to update `CheckBoxList` then do it in `RowDataBound` event.

Comment: yes there is only one. I Have given an image of student form in the post.